# Check ICD10 via regex

Tags: regex

I need to check icd10 code this code generate with few condition

1. min length is 3.
2. first character is letter and not is 'U'.
3. second and third is digit.
4. fourth is dot(.)
5. fifth to eight charactor is letter or digit.

Ex.:

Right : "A18.32","A28.2","A04.0","A18.R252", "A18", "A18.52", "R18", "R18."

Wrong : "A184.32","U18","111."

Comment: What's not working with your expression?

Comment: Oh, some people could not resist the flood of poor regex questions and started spoon-feeding. Run out of close votes?...

Comment: Besides the quality of the question, I'm still wondering about the 1st condition: min length is 3.. when would 1 fail if the rest are met?

Answer (score 9):

is this an icd-10-cm code you are looking to verify.

if so I believe that the 3rd digit is alpha or numeric

taken from page 7
https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD10/downloads/032310_ICD10_Slides.pdf

if so the following regular expression should validate.

```
^([a-tA-T]|[v-zV-Z])\d[a-zA-Z0-9](\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

otherwise you can edit the above regular expression to check characte 2 and 3 as numeric.

```
^([a-tA-T]|[v-zV-Z])\d{2}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like so: `^[A-TV-Z]\d{2}(\.[A-Z\d]{0,4})?$`. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJ8xP4/1).

This is how the answer satisfies your condition:

1. Min length is 3: `^[A-TV-Z]\d{2}...$` attempts to match a letter and 2 digits. The `^` and `$` ensure that there is nothing else in the string which does not satisfy the regular expression. This segment: `(\.[A-Z\d]{0,4})?` is surrounded by the `?` operator: `(...)?`. This means that the content within the round brackets may or may not be there.
2. First character is letter and not is 'U'. This is satisfied by `[A-TV-Z]`, which matches all the upper case letters which are between `A` and `T`, `V` and `Z` inclusive. This omits the letter `U`.
3. Second and third is digit. `\d{2}` means match two digits.
4. Fourth is dot(.): This is satisfied by `\.`. The extra `\` is needed because the period character is a special character in regular expressions, which means *match any character* (exception new lines, unless a special option is passed along).
5. Fifth to eight charactor is letter or digit. `[A-Z\d]{0,4}` means any letter or digits, repeated between 0 and 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\b[a-tv-zA-TV-Z]\d{2}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{,4})?\b
```

I assume by your example the dot and everything after it is optional

This regex will match a word boundary `\b`, a letter other than u or U `[a-tv-zA-TV-Z]`, two digits `\d{2}` and then an optional dot followed by 0-4 letters or digits `(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{,4})?` and a second word boundary `\b`

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I had the same issue of validating ICD-10 codes, so it seemed worth an updated answer.

As it turns out, there are two flavors of ICD-10 codes: [ICD-10-CM](https://www.cms.gov/medicare/icd-10/2021-icd-10-cm) and [ICD-10-PCS](https://www.cms.gov/medicare/icd-10/2021-icd-10-pcs). From their [usage](https://www.cms.gov/files/document/2021-coding-guidelines-updated-12162020.pdf) [guidelines](http://2021%20Official%20ICD-10-PCS%20Coding%20Guidelines%20-%20Updated%20December%201,%202020%20(PDF)):

> The ICD-10-CM is a morbidity classification published by the United
> States for classifying diagnoses and reason for visits in all health
> care settings.

*and*

> The ICD-10-PCS is a procedure classification published by the United
> States for classifying procedures performed in hospital inpatient
> health care settings.

### Both Sets

In both the ICD-10-CM and ICD-10-PCS coding systems, you can validate the *structure* of a code with a regular expression, but validating the *content* (in terms of which specific combinations of letters and numbers are valid) may be technically possible, but is practically infeasible. A [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) would be a better bet.

### ICD-10-CM

From the Conventions section of the guidelines:

> #### Format and Structure:
>
> The ICD-10-CM Tabular List contains categories, subcategories and
> codes. Characters for categories, subcategories and codes may be
> either a letter or a number. All categories are 3 characters. A
> three-character category that has no further subdivision is equivalent
> to a code. Subcategories are either 4 or 5 characters. Codes may be 3,
> 4, 5, 6 or 7 characters. That is, each level of subdivision after a
> category is a subcategory. The final level of subdivision is a code.
> Codes that have applicable 7th characters are still referred to as
> codes, not subcategories. A code that has an applicable 7th character
> is considered invalid without the 7th character.

According to this specification, you'd expect a valid regular expression would look like this:

```
 ^\w{3,7}$
```

However, a review of the *actual values* shows that, in all cases, the first character is an upper case letter, the second character is a digit, and any alphabetic characters in the remaining available positions are upper case as well. As such, you can use this information to more precisely specify what you're validating:

```
 ^[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]{1,5}$
```

If you want to allow for a possible period in the fourth position followed by up to four more characters as specified by the OP:

```
 ^[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d](\.[A-Z\d]{0,4})?$
```

### ICD-10-PCS

From the Conventions section of the guidelines:

> One of 34 possible values can be assigned to each axis of
> classification in the seven character code: they are the numbers 0
> through 9 and the alphabet (except I and O because they are easily
> confused with the numbers 1 and 0). The number of unique values used
> in an axis of classification differs as needed...As with words in their
> context, the meaning of any single value is a combination of its axis
> of classification and any preceding values on which it may be
> dependent...*Within a PCS table, valid codes include all combinations
> of choices in characters 4 through 7 contained in the same row of the
> table. [For example], 0JHT3VZ is a valid code, and 0JHW3VZ is
> **not** a valid code.*

So to validate the structure of an ICD-10-PCS code:

```
 ^[A-HJ-NP-Z\d]{7}$
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this exp simple :

```
'^([A-TV-Za-tv-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}|[A-TV-Za-tv-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})$'
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the OPs question (or, well, it answers, but the answer is wrong) (it doesn't cater for just digits for the second and third entry)